# Electron building issue for server along with the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app that has the folder structure -

> Public -> index.html, main.js
>
> Server -> server.js
>
> src -> (all the front end app styling and components)

The server runs on localhost:3001 and listens to Post and Get commands from the front end that submits requests to the localhost:3001/exampleReq

This is my package.json for the root

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.37",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.0.16",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.28.0",
    "antd": "4.17.0-alpha.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-dnd": "latest",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "latest",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-filetree-electron": "^1.2.2",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.17.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.6",
    "react-window": "^1.8.6",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"yarn electron:start\" \"cd server && yarn start server\"",
    "electron:build": "yarn build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
    "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron ."
  },
  "build": {
    "extends": null,
    "appId": "com.example.electron-cra",
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^11.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "wait-on": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "src/Auto"
  ]
}
```

When I run `yarn electron:serve` everything works and both the app and server run.

When I do `yarn electron:build` the front end stuff gets compiled but not the server. I don't believe the server is being linked at all.

This is the package.json for the server folder:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "type": "commonjs",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the build part so that I can have an .exe or .dmg where once opened everything works the same as when running `electron:serve`?

Here's how `electron:serve` links the server

```
 "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"yarn electron:start\" \"cd server && yarn start server\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution to this would be to bring all the server code inside public. I guess this is an answer but would like to keep the folders separate if possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Jalen! Welcome to SO! Please don't post additional information as an answer when it can be included in the post. People will see that there has been an answer and may choose not to look into the post!

Comment: My bad, that makes sense.